# Python: how can I grep a string from class 'selenium...'

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to know whether IE correctly start or some problems like "Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL<> return HRESULT 8007007A" is encountered. So I intend to grep "selenium" from driver but the following error "type 'WebDriver' is not iterable" is shown. How could I solve it? Thanks!

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Ie()
>>> other_string = "Use selenium to control IE"
>>> "selenium" in other_string
True
>>> print (driver)
<selenium.webdriver.ie.webdriver.WebDriver (session="daa6e29c-5112-4bc7-8df3-6c13a7a9412f")>
>>> "selenium" in driver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    "selenium" in driver
TypeError: argument of type 'WebDriver' is not iterable
>>> type (other_string)
<class 'str'>
>>> type (driver)
<class 'selenium.webdriver.ie.webdriver.WebDriver'>
```

Comment: Why do you think "selenium" won't be in the class name if it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
>>>"selenium" in str(driver)
```

Or perhaps more reliably:

```
>>>"selenium" in driver.__class__
```

Comment: It's what I need! Thanks!

Comment: But be careful. If someone change the def __str__() method in WebDriver class.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!